# What is the best way to make a variable threadsafe?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

An issue has arisen due to a code refactor, what is the best solution in this case?

The issue is that the DbConnection was refactored from a local method variable into a class variable.
The application is multithreaded. 
It appeared that the issue is with the DbConnection object being shared when it is a member variable.
What is the best solution? leave it as a local method varaible?

```
public IDataReader Execute(CommandBehavior behavior, string[] parameterNames, object[] arguments)
{

        DbConnection conn = null;
        try
        {

            conn = Connection.CreateConnection();

            DbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = StoredProcedureName;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;



           //     ..................................................

            // Perform the call.                        
            return DataCachingContext.SetCachedData(call, cmd.ExecuteReader(behavior));

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //..........................
        }
        finally
        {
            //
        }

}
```

Just to clarify, here is the version which causes issue. with a runtime exception, issues with indexing into ResultSets, this is most likely due to the connection being overwritten.

```
DbConnection _conn = null;

public IDataReader Execute(CommandBehavior behavior, string[] parameterNames, object[] arguments)
{

        try
        {

            _conn = Connection.CreateConnection();

            DbCommand cmd = _conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = StoredProcedureName;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;



           //     ..................................................

            // Perform the call.                        
            return DataCachingContext.SetCachedData(call, cmd.ExecuteReader(behavior));

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //..........................
        }
        finally
        {
            //
        }

}
```

After more investigation it looks like the DbConnection variable was made a class variable to enable unit testing. When it's a local variable there's no way to test it's value. The state of the DbConnection was being tested

Comment: Best way would be to research [tag:thread-safety] and [tag:multithreading]. This question has been asked here hundreds of times; possibly has already been asked _today_.

Comment: I'm not seeing any problems here except that you stated that the DbConnection was a class variable and here it is clearly a local variable, have you declared it twice? If that's not the problem we need more details.

Comment: I don't see any thread on your code. Is `DataCachingContext` the shared object? Is it `static`?

Comment: You generally don’t make a variable thread safe. You make *access to it* thread safe *under specific circumstances*. This already implies the solution: *don’t* access a variable in a cross-thread manner, if avoidable (and it usually is). This is the safest method.

Comment: You will get a better answer if you can be more specific about the problem you are having.  At first glance it doesn't appear that you will have the problem you described with the specific code you posted, and you didn't say whether or not you're getting an error message, or what the error message says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The application is multithreaded. It appeared that the issue is with the DbConnection object being shared when it is a member variable. What is the best solution? leave it as a local method varaible?

Yes, a good pattern for using `DbConnection` is to create and dispose the connection in a method (storing it in local variable). Behind the scenes the connections are pooled so there is no significant overhead in doing it like this. You also avoid having to deal with shared state and locks.

The code provided in the question does exactly what I describe here.

Comment: After more investigation it looks like the DbConnection variable was made a class variable to enable unit testing. When it's a local variable there's no way to test it's value. The state of the DbConnection was being tested.

Comment: Actually you can implement and pass a `DbProviderFactory` to your class in order to produce mock connections for unit tests: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971499.aspx

Comment: Mudu,  I don't understand this. Can you explain? Now I'm looking for an alternative to a class variable so that I can test the State of the DbConnection from my unit tests. Is there some way to get the connection from some global storage? and then test its state.

Comment: @learnerplates: Create class `TestDbProviderFactory` that derives from `DbProviderFactory` and implement all the necessary methods. You have to provide mock objects to allow your tests to run (e.g. a `TestConnection` that derives from `DbConnection` and so on). In test code use `TestDbProviderFactory` and in production code use the real provider, e.g. `SqlClientFactory` or whatever you are using. You can use dependency injetion to inject the desired `DbProviderFactory` into your class.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for the [lock statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
.

> lock ensures that one thread does not enter a critical section of code while another thread is in the critical section. If another thread attempts to enter a locked code, it will wait, block, until the object is released.

Comment: Just be sure to handle well your exceptions to avoid not releasing the object.

Comment: @Andre Unnecessary. Using `lock` takes care of that automatically – in fact, that’s the whole point of using `lock`, rather than `Monitor.Enter`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph If an exception occurs inside the `using` block, will the object still be freed?

Comment: @AndreCalil To repeat, that is the whole reason for the existence of the `lock` statement. Otherwise, we wouldn’t need a language construct, we could just use `Monitor.Enter` / `Monitor.Exit`.

Comment: My bad, I meant `lock`, not `using` statement. Anyway, thanks. I thought that an exception would change the processing flow and let the object locked.

Answer (score 1):

Database connection objects should generally be local variables, because a database connection is a relatively expensive resource to keep open for any length of time. The danger with having the database connection as a class variable is that the connection will be opened when the object is instantiated, and will then stay open until the class is disposed. This can result in locks not being released in a timely fashion, and long running transactions, which can seriously affect performance.

It is much better to open the connection just before you need it (e.g., to call a stored procedure, execute a SQL statement), and close/dispose it immediately afterward. Under the covers the database connections are usually cached anyway, which minimises the overhead in repeatedly opening and closing connections, because when you open a connection in the code, the chances are you will be getting an already open connection from the cache.

Answer (score 1):

The MSDN documentation says on [`DbConnection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnection.aspx):

> Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

Therefore it's - in my opinion - hardly a good idea to keep it as a class variable. Even though your implementation might be thread-safe, it's risky to assume so. You can work with locks to avoid threading issues, but these approaches typically tend to scale badly. So, better keep the object local.

If you are worrying about performance in case too many connections are opened and closed all the time, have a look at [SQL Server Connection Pooling (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx) which does quite a good job pooling actual connections rather than `DbConnection` objects.

Answer (score 0):

In both code snippets you create new Connection. What was the intent of making connection a class variable then? From the code you posted, it looks like the connection should be local variable.